How to get a windows shell Drop Handler to work for folders
I am trying to write a windows shell extension. My goal is to have a handler that can handle all drag and drop operations on a folder. When files are dropped on a folder, I want to execute my business logic which will either

Take control of the drag and drop operation OR
Let windows do its default behavior.

I am using SharpShell as an easy way to implement the shell extension. It works, but not as i expected. It seems like the shell extension lets you handle the case of "what if a file is dropped on a FILE".  Like, if i drop a PDF on a text file, I can intercept that.  But DragEnter or Drop is never called when dragging (and dropping) files on a folder.
Is what I want to do supported without a namespace extension?
[ComVisible(true)]
[COMServerAssociation(AssociationType.AllFilesAndFolders)]
public class MyDropHandler : SharpDropHandler
{
    protected override void DragEnter(DragEventArgs dragEventArgs)
    {
        dragEventArgs.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }

    protected override void Drop(DragEventArgs dragEventArgs)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
    }
}


You might want to try to declare your COM object in HKCU\Software\Classes\Directory\shellex\DragDropHandlers (non admin) or HKCR\Directory\shellex\DragDropHandlers, and also replacing Directory by Folder or AllFilesystemObjects

@SimonMourier Thanks Simon. I have tried those things, and they don't seem to work.

It should work, but DragDropHandlers must support IContextMenu and IShellExtInit (optionally IObjectWithSite) see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/reg-shell-exts#handler-names
